# to love something "so bad"

Tags: idioms

In the spoken English if someone loves something **so-bad** it means that he likes it very much. is it right?

My question if to the ears of the native English speakers is it sounded negatively that someone loves **so-bad**.

Comment: Native speakers do not say that we "*love* someone|something so bad". Rather we say that we *want* or *need* something or someone so bad.   **bad** describes the intensity of need, desire, lack, want, yearning.

Comment: But I found a lot of results with to love someone so bad. Is it incorrect or unacceptable between native English speakers? 
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22when+you+love+someone+so+bad%22

Comment: and here: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22love+someone+so+bad%22

Comment: A point of procedure: you cannot cite Google searches as evidence without additional proof that the speakers/authors are native English speakers.

Comment: It's easy to see in the first result that there is song of Alesha Dixon which states such sentence. Alesha Dixon (born 7 October 1978) is a British singer. This is just one example only but there are more there.

Comment: Another point of procedure: try to find prose attestations over song lyrics. The lyrics also say 'You can't think of nothing else" which would not be considered "standard" English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's right. That's the adverbial sense of "bad", which is equivalent to "badly". The following definition of "badly" describes the usage you're talking about (From *Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged*):

> 2a:  very much:  to a great or intense degree
>   *want something badly*
>   *badly in need of help*

So no, it doesn't sound negative to a native speaker because we are used to that usage.

(Note that you don't need to put a hyphen between "so" and "bad".)